# Responsibility of Zookeeper Vs Controller Broker in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I understand Broker Controller is responsible for managing all the brokers in the cluser. As per my understanding ZooKeeper helps in identifying Controller.

Is the resposibility of ZooKeeper limited to identifying Controller or Zookeeper has more responsibility in management of cluster.

Secondly, the Producer / Consumers take the broker list to identify the state of the cluster, why Producer / Consumers doesn't interact with zoo-keeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to KIP-500 (removal of Zookeeper), Zookeepeer maintains the list of topics, their replica placements, Kafka ACLs, among other details more than simply leader-election facilities

> why Producer / Consumers doesn't interact with zoo-keeper?

They *used to* (Kafka clients older than 0.9), but this was removed to ease the maintenance burden and simplify the codebase for a rewritten client library.

Comment: My thought was Controller will maintain the details of Topics, Leader Selection, Replicas etc. Is it incorrect?  Can you explain the responsibilities of ZooKeeper vs Controller.

What I meant by Consumer interacting with Broker instead of zookeeper is 
props.put("bootstrap.servers",...)
My query was shouldn't the Consumer contact the zookeeper instead broker.

After your ans, I looked https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client
It says ".. as in the old consumer and the producer, we need to configure an initial list of brokers..."

Comment: 1) _thought was Controller will maintain_  - No. [Refer docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#impl_zookeeper). 2) _shouldn't the Consumer contact the zookeeper instead broker_. No, not directly, at least. The Metadata request _eventually_ reaches Zookeeper, but clients above version 0.9 should never communicate with ZK directly as it will eventually be removed entirely within the next year or so

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will go through the doc. Out of curiosity, I have a question though ZK will be removed after some time and the clients above version 0.9 should never communicate with ZK directly. But for earlier clients, why the commuication was via the brokers and not directly to the ZK, if the metadata request was eventually reaching to ZK only.

Comment: Because produce and consume requests are sent and handled by brokers... I don't understand what you're trying to ask

Comment: My question is, client sets "bootstrap.servers" property. The bootstrap server is used to get the cluster metadata (which is eventually provided by the Zookeeper). Why client doesn't directly interact with Zookeeper to get cluster metadata?

Comment: Because the Zookeeper server doesn't know how to process that [TCP request payload](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html)